# Solr Insertion Using java

Tags: java, solr, solrj

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FeedIntoSolr{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SolrServerException {
        HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");

        for(int i=0;i<1000;++i) {
            SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
            doc.addField("cat", "book");
            doc.addField("id", "book-" + i);
            doc.addField("name", "The Legend of the Hobbit part " + i);
            server.add(doc);
            if(i%100==0) 
                server.commit();  // periodically flush
        }
        server.commit();
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase
    at FeedIntoSolr.main(FeedIntoSolr.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing httpclient's jar in your [classpath](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase.html).

Ensure you have this jar in your classpath and you should get rid of this error.

Comment: I have added commons-httpclient-2.0.jar but not working

Comment: Whats the error after you added library? There may be many more libs that you may want to add?

Comment: I got the same error which was comming before adding the httpclient library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add http client implementation
You can update your pom.xml with maven

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

Or download it at https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi and add it to the classpath in Eclipse with Project > Properties > Build Path

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for responding..I got the answer of question asked by me.

1)first of all you need to add the jar files which is already available in solr folder(you will see when you unzipped it)

2)Jar Files in the folder **solr-5.2.1->dist( add only solr-solrj-5.2.1.jar in classpath) and solr->dist->solrj-lib(add all jar in classpath)**

3)you have to add two another file **commons-logging-1.2.jar** and **slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar**

This is working for me..